# SQL Get values between two telephone numbers

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Would it be possible to get values in between two phone numbers. e.g.

```
DECLARE @startrange VARCHAR(20) = '1132282220'  
DECLARE @endrange VARCHAR(20) = '1132282230'
```

Id imagine you convert these variables to BIGINT .

Desired output:

> 1132282220 1132282221 1132282222
>   1132282223... 1132282230

Comment: Do you want all phone numbers in a table or or possible numbers that might exist between the two?

Comment: All phone numbers please

Comment: You could use a [Tally Table](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Editorial/130023/) or a [Recursive CTE](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get values by table rows you can use next SQL code

```
DECLARE @startrange VARCHAR(20),
        @endrange VARCHAR(20),
        @startrange_ BIGINT,
        @endrange_ BIGINT

DECLARE @result_tbl TABLE(VALUE BIGINT)

SET @startrange = '1132282220'
SET @endrange = '1132282230'
SET @startrange_ = CAST(@startrange AS BIGINT)
SET @endrange_ = CAST(@endrange AS BIGINT)

WHILE @startrange_ <= @endrange_
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @result_tbl VALUES(@startrange_)

    SET @startrange_ = @startrange_ + 1
END

SELECT * FROM @result_tbl AS RT
```

If you want to get values in one row you can use code like this

```
DECLARE @startrange VARCHAR(20),
        @endrange VARCHAR(20),
        @startrange_ BIGINT,
        @endrange_ BIGINT

DECLARE @output_value VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @startrange = '1132282220'
SET @endrange = '1132282230'
SET @startrange_ = CAST(@startrange AS BIGINT)
SET @endrange_ = CAST(@endrange AS BIGINT)

WHILE @startrange_ <= @endrange_
BEGIN
    SET @output_value = ISNULL(@output_value, '') 
                            + CAST(@startrange_ AS VARCHAR) + ' ' 

    SET @startrange_ = @startrange_ + 1
END

SELECT RTRIM(@output_value)
```

Also I've written `recursive CTE` solution to solve this task

```
DECLARE @startrange VARCHAR(20),
        @endrange VARCHAR(20),
        @startrange_ BIGINT,
        @endrange_ BIGINT

DECLARE @output_value VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @startrange = '1132282220'
SET @endrange = '1132282230'
SET @startrange_ = CAST(@startrange AS BIGINT)
SET @endrange_ = CAST(@endrange AS BIGINT)

;WITH Result AS(
SELECT @startrange_ AS startrange
UNION ALL
SELECT startrange + 1 FROM Result
WHERE startrange < @endrange_)

SELECT @output_value = ISNULL(@output_value, '') 
                        + CAST(startrange AS VARCHAR) + ' '
FROM Result

SELECT RTRIM(@output_value)
```